# Run a web scraper most efficient in React / Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, web-scraping, mern

I'm running a web scraper in my React (MERN STACK) web app. I'm using request-promise (rp) and cheerio library to fetch url/html.

I have this method to run in componentWillMount() every times a user goes to the X page. The array it fetches are around 80-150 elements long with 4-5 objects. But it doesn't seem very efficient to run it every time a user enters that X page. So is there a better way to do it? Sometimes it takes a while before the array "loads" / from 5 seconds and up to 30-40 seconds at most.

One option I wondered if was possible is a fetch method running every 15 minutes (for the whole server) or so and posting it to my MongoDB, then retrieving when user enters that X page instead. Is that possible in any way? Like a extern method without having anyone on the page?

Or is there any script you could run on your desktop to run every 15 minutes to push data to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Heroku Scheduler to set up a cron job, works great.